# Returning null or a value in C#

Tags: c#, null

I come from a strong Java background and I am very used to this kind of code:

```
Object o = foo();
if (o == null) {
    bar();
} else {
    somethingElse();
}

public Object foo() {
//code....
if (..) {
    return Object;
} else {
    return null;
```

But c# does not allow this. I want a function that returns an object if it has been found or return null if there is not such instance. What is the way to go about it in c#?

Comment: Why do you think this isn't possible in C#?

Comment: If you will write exact lines of code in C# - you will get exactly the same result you want.

Comment: Do you mean [nullable types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx)? This is the only way how value type *can return* `null`.

Comment: Please provide:
1.) The code that's not compiling in c#  or\ and the code in Java
2.) The compilation error you receive from the c# compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing this in C#? The code you posted should work exactly the same way in C#, and there's no reason to think that a simple null check would be different.

However, unlike Java, C# also offers a more idiomatic way of handling nulls. C# has the `??` operator, which is fairly similar to the ternary `?` operator, but checks for null.

```
Object o = foo();
Object result = o ?? somethingElse();
```

That snippet will call `foo()` and assign it to `result` if `o` is NOT null, or call `somethingElse()` if `o` is null.

Note that for value types, C# has the concept of nullable types, unlike Java. In Java,

```
int x = null;
```

is not valid. It's also not valid in C#, but you can create a nullable int. That means a value type (int in this case) that can also have `null` as a value.

```
int? x = null;
```

That is valid C# code.

Comment: `o ?? processObject(o) : somethingElse()` should not compile. you are correct that with `c = a ?? b` if `a` is not null, then `c` will be `a`, otherwise `c` will be `b`. But the `x : y` part does not make sense here.

Comment: Fixed the example, so much for answering while actually thinking of Java's ternary.